# Possible to overwriting a method used in a callback?

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

Is this possible?  I'm trying to overwrite a javascript method after my page has been loaded.  The code in question looks similar to this:

```
  myObject = Backbone.ViewManager.BaseView.extend({
     myMethod: function() {
       alert("in old method definition");
     },
     initialize: function() {
       var a = this;
       Our.Events.on("alertEvent", function(){
          a.myMethod();
       }
     }
  );
```

(The `Backbone.ViewManager` bit is just a way to create an object in javascript using a framework and not important here.)

Note the event callback defined above in the `initialize` method.  We initialize the objects as soon as they're created.

After my page has loaded I tried to redefine `myMethod` to alert a different message.  But when the `alertEvent` fires the original message appears in the alert.

I assume this is because of a closure, that redefining the method on `myObject` after its been initialized won't affect the definition pointed to by `a`?  If that's the case, is there something I can do to change the definition used by `a`, or am I out of luck?

Comment: It should work - show us a reproducing example (jsfiddle link or stack snippet).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to define `myMethod` on the object you create which will override the prototype `myMethod`. What you have written should be able to work because you arn't referencing myMethod directly, but through the a object.

The following works for me

```
function ObjCstr(){}
ObjCstr.prototype.myMethod = function(){ alert("Old Message"); };
ObjCstr.prototype.callMyMethod = function(){
    var a = this;
    return function(){ a.myMethod(); };
};

var test = new ObjCstr();
var fakeListener = test.callMyMethod();

fakeListener(); // "OldMessage"
test.myMethod = function(){ alert("Overridden!"); };
fakeListener(); // "Overridden!"
```